# Can not see my Envion tokens on MEW

Tags: wallets

I tried everything in order to see my Envion tokens on MEW myetherwallet, I tried contract adress, symbol, decimals ... I also tried with Envion private key and mnemonic phrase ... I bought Envion tokens with Bitcoins and maybe this is the problem ... I can only see my tokens on Envion dashboard, but not in MEW or Metamask ... if someone knows what is the problem, please help, I was in contact with Envion support team, but they are not helping

Comment: Possibly related to this issue? https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/ethereum-lists/issues/357

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple tokens called Envion with different contract addresses, you need to make sure you are adding the correct one otherwise it will show that you have 0 balance. If you check on etherscan.io, under "view tokens", click on the token, then it'll take you to a page where it shows you all the info needed to add the token to your interface with the correct address to use.